# ¿Agrupar por día, filtrar valores indeseados, desagrupar y agrupar por tramos horarios?

Tags: mysql, sql, visualización-de-datos

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de conteo de entradas de clientes en tienda. Algunas tiendas no apagan sus dispositivos de conteo los días de inactividad, con lo cual en la base de datos se registran ceros cuando en realidad deberían ser valores nulos, que puedo filtrar de forma efectiva y fácil mediante la consulta SQL (MySQL) que envía los datos a mi BI (desarrollado con una aplicación no muy conocida, Tabulae).

Al hacer recuentos totales, dado que son sumatorios, los ceros no influyen, pero al calcular valores medios estos sufren una distorsión a la baja. Por lo tanto, se ha decidido que en aquellos *widgets* que muestren medias se ha de aplicar un filtro que elimine las tiendas en aquellos días en los que hay menos de 10 registros; es decir, en aquellos gráficos o KPIs que muestren totales no hay problema -y de hecho se prefiere- en que aparezcan esos ceros -permiten identificar tiendas que están haciendo algo extraño-, pero en aquellos que calculen medias han de ser filtrados antes de hacer el promedio.

Mediante el propio BI, esto resulta fácil para niveles de visualización diarios o superiores: se agrupan las entradas por tienda y por día, se aplica un filtro para valores inferiores a 10, y posteriormente se calculan las medias o se hacen más agrupaciones con los registros que superan el filtro.

Sin embargo, los datos también se visualizan por tramos horarios, con lo cual una vez realizado el filtrado por tienda y por día necesitaría desagrupar los registros para poder agruparlos de nuevo por tramo. No veo la forma de hacerlo con mi BI, y mi duda es si siquiera es algo que se pueda hacer a nivel de SQL.

Si fuera posible hacerlo a nivel de SQL, no habría problema en crear dos *datasets*, uno que filtre los ceros y otro que no, para emplear cada uno donde sea necesario.

Es una pregunta un tanto abierta, espero que podáis orientarme al respecto. Gracias por adelantado.

EDITO:

Se me ocurre que podría hacer algo así:

```
SELECT
    tienda,
    dia
    FROM 
        tabla
    GROUP BY
        tienda,
        dia
    HAVING
        sum(entradas) < 10
;
```

Así tendría las duplas (tienda, dia) que quiero eliminar; ¿esto se podría encajar como subconsulta en el `WHERE`de la consulta que agrupa por tramos para que no tenga en cuenta esas tiendas para esos días?

O, mejor aún, marcar esas duplas con un buleano y poder usar el mismo *dataset* en todos los casos; suponiendo que los tramos horarios fueran sólo 2:

```
tienda dia tramo eliminar
1      1   9     1
1      1   10    1
1      2   9     0
1      2   10    0
1      3   9     0
1      3   10    0
2      1   9     0
2      1   10    0
2      2   9     1
2      2   10    1
2      3   9     0
2      3   10    0
```

¿Cómo lo veis?

Comment: a ver, he leído todo varias veces y todavía tengo dudas (lo siento, hoy estoy espesa), tú quieres que esas entradas en la base de datos no lleguen a entrar, verdad? si es así se me ocurren dos soluciones: 1.- bloquearlo desde código . 2.- bloquearlo desde la base de datos. Si lo bloqueas desde código puedes tener algo tipo hangfire, que te borre periodicamente las entradas que no quieres (recurrent jobs o tareas recurrentes, creo que en linux hay algo similar que se llama crontab), o bien puedes directamente ver si no hay entradas y si ese es el caso no guardar nada en la base de datos.

Comment: me ha quedado largo, así que va en otro comentario. 2.- mira los triggers en la base de datos. Estos saltan cuando intentas guardar algo en la tabla correspondiente, puedes hacer algo en plan verificación de datos y si no cumplen tus reglas que no se graben.

Comment: No te preocupes, he editado la pregunta porque me habían quedado algunas cosas sin explicar.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es controlar la visualización de los datos, entonces con if/else y vistas (views), mira también store procedures, para tener un store proc que te lo calcule todo o te lo saque todo en función de lo que necesites, pero claro, tendrías que tocar código para que llamase al store procedure

Comment: distinct(), para no tener duplicados?

Comment: No me queda claro si buscas el query o que estarias buscando...

Answer (score 1):

Tienes una subconsulta de dias/tiendas con pocos movimientos y quieres usarla para filtrar los datos en otra consulta, la forma más sencilla es usar el `NOT EXISTS( ... )`

```
SELECT *
       FROM tabla T
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                            FROM tabla T1
                            WHERE T.tienda = T1.tienda
                               AND T.dia = T1.dia                         
                            GROUP BY T1.tienda, T1.dia
                            HAVING sum(entradas) < 10
                )
```